# How does a wave become a color?

Tags: visible-light, frequency

I am a mathematician and not a physicist, so please be gentle to me.

The best explanation I found so far about light waves was here: https://youtu.be/7eutept5h0Q

If I got it right, then light is a particle without mass which has magnetic and electric energy and this energy is oscillating all the time. When one spots this particle, one sees a color which depends on the frequency of the oscillating energy. Is that correct?

Also every color in the below diagram may be observed by a single particle.

[image]

All other colors that don't appear in the diagram (like white color) have to be a collection of light particles of differed frequencies which will appear to us as a single color?

Comment: Yes that is all correct. But the most important reason is that we have 3 types of cells in our eye each for Red Green and Blue.  Our brain is finally what makes us perceive color.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You show above .the visible light frequencies, which are the colors of the rainbow. Visible light is composed out of elementary particles called photons whose energy is given by $E=hν$, which are mathematically described by wavefunctions that are solutions of the quantized Maxwell equations. A [quantum superposition of zillions of photons](https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) build up the classical electromagnetic wave. Visible frequencies are a small part of [the spectrum.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum).

But there is another aspect of color, called [color perception](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html), what hits the retina in our eye and the brain assigns a color to it.

[image]

So

> If I got it right, then light is a particle

No, light is a superposition of quantum mechanical zero mass photons

> which has magnetic and electric energy and this energy is oscillating all the time.

Only in the superposed  composed of  zillions of photons classical wave. The particle/photon has a fixed energy and is neutral, the electric and magnetic fields are built up by the superposition of zillions of photons. The photon itself, just has energy, and spin and momentum. The electric and magnetic fields are in the [complex wavefunction](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169) whose [complex conjugate squared](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) gives the probability of finding a photon at x,y,z. See [this experiment.](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/)

> So seeing a color does not define uniquely the frequency.

that is correct.

For 
 comments:
To answer  whether single photons/ quanat  exist, [here is](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) the double slit experiment single photon at a time

[image]

> Single-photon camera recording of photons from a double slit illuminated by very weak laser light. Left to right: single frame, superposition of 200, 1’000, and 500’000 frames.

It is a quantum of the light, and the frequency can be extracted from using slit width, distance  and the accumulated interference pattern of the classical manifestation. After all the wave nature is in the probability distribution displayed nicely here on the right.

Is it a wave packet hitting singly and seemingly randomly on the left? each point could be modeled with a narrow wavepacket consistent with the frequency.

For absorption and emission  sectra , the lines have a width, and the wavepacket if within the frequency width will act as one quantum, imo.

Comment: *The particle/photon has a fixed energy*. Not true. A photon like any other quantum system, may well be in a superposition of eigenstates of energy. Even very far from a "monochromatic" photon. The widespread formula $E=h\nu$ is (approximately) true only in very special situations, e.g. in emission by transition of two discrete energy levels of an atom.

Comment: @ElioFabri for the spectrum shown in the question there is monochromaticity ( withn the heisenberg uncertaint)y. In QED the operator creating a photon has a specific energy. (in the link discussing how classical fields emerger from quantum)

Comment: @ElioFabri can you give an example of a photon in superposition? These visible photons are quantized are created by atomic transitions, are you thinking of radio waves and microwaves produced by antennas?

Comment: @PhysicsDave In general, elementary particle wave functions used in quantum field theory are plane waves, and these are not a good model for detected footprints of photons, as here https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/ . This is solved by the wavepacket as a model of a detected particle  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html  when treated in qft

Comment: @PhysicsDave Look for "quantum beats" in wiki. For a different instance, think of femtosecond laser pulses, today commonplace in optics labs. A pulse 6 fs long for visible light means photons of average energy of few eV in a superposition of energy eigenstates wide about 1 eV.

Comment: @AnnaV 1. The spctrum may well be made by monochromatic photons but the OP in his post clearly shows he believes it's a general property of
photons and this is false. 2. Quite obvious that in QED is a general
practice to develop field operators in energy (and momentum) eigenstates. But this doesn't imply that photons of non-definite energy can't exist - in fact that's the rule.

Comment: @ElioFabri  if they do not have a definite energy when caught in a spectrum, as above they are virtual and not measurable.

Comment: @AnnaV When caught in a spectrum, yes. Surely the've passed a grating or some other energy measuring instrument. (BTW. A grating has for
non-monocromatic photons just the same effect than non-uniform field has for spin in Stern-Gerlach experiment - it entangles energy with position.) But our discussion is about photons in general, not in that special situation. The issue is: do photons with non definite energy exist? I've asserted they do. As far as I could understand, you give the opposite answer.

Comment: @ElioFabri  only in wave packet models , where the frequencies are adjacent within the   HUP, . When measured one frquency appears,, things that cannot be measured are mathematical constructs  and are called virtual.. I am an experimentalist, , a doubting thomas " Except I shall see in his hands the print of the nails, and put my finger into the print of the nails, and thrust my hand into his side, I will not believe"

Comment: @ElioFabri In the femto second laser pulse, I can understand the superposition of say 1000 photons in a small space of the EM field, can we consider this 1 photon?  Or the 1000 photons in the pulse were created by roughly 1000 excited atoms and when the photons are observed they can only be absorbed one at a time ... i.e everything is still a quanta?  Do the quanta have non-definite energy or is it the packet as a whole (or both)?  By non-definite do you mean plus or minus 0.1%, i.e. small variation or combinations of quanta that produce higher energy photons?

Comment: @AnnaV Yes the wave packet model better explains the genesis of photon ... but can we still perceive this multifrequency photon as a single quanta.  As a single quanta with a very well defined packet energy it can only be absorbed (or observed) in its entirety?

Comment: @ElioFabri   I found this very interesting article on quantum beats, around late 1970s.  https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/quantum.beats.pdf

Comment: @PhysicsDave see the single photon plot I edited in my answer

Answer (score 2):

The color is not related to frequency in 1 to 1 relationship. Frequency is a well defined, measurable property of the light. Color is a sensation which depends on the frequencies of the light hitting the retina but not in a simple way. You can get the same sensation (color) either by light with a narrow range of frequency (for example  green produced by a laser pointer) or by mixing light with different frequencies (like mixing blue and yellow may result in the sensation of green too). So yes, the color depends on the frequency range of the light. It is more common that light hitting the eye is a mixture of waves with a wide range of frequencies so this is how we get the many shades of colors. The sensation of color may depend also on the environment, the brightness of the object and the background.

Comment: You're confusing additive and subtractive color here. If you _add_ yellow and blue _light_, you'll perceive the result as _white_ -- your eye sees yellow as "red plus green ", and so it sees yellow + blue as "red + green + blue" = white. This is in fact how most "white" LEDs work; they contain a blue emitter and a phosphor that fluoresces yellow under blue illumination.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, light is an oscillation in the electro-magnetic field, with a certain frequency (and other properties, but they are irrelevant to the question).

The photo-receptors in the human eye are sensitive to light with frequencies that correspond to wavelengths of ~380nm to ~780nm (wavelength is inversely proportional to frequency) - this is called the visible range.

every frequency or combination of frequencies in the visible range are perceived as a color by our brain. Any frequency outside the visible are, well, invisible to our eyes.